# API /answers/{id}/flags/add route has multiple bugs

Tags: support, bug, flags, api

The API route to [flag an answer](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-answer-flag) has a couple of issues. The first of these may or may not be a bug, but the second definitely is.

Firstly, sending a request that's apparently identical to the example request that the API console sends fails. On trying to flag Stack Overflow answer #40769255, the API console sends the following parameters to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/40769255/flags/add`:

```
id: 40769255
option_id: 22992
key: my API key
access_token: my write token
preview: true
filter: default
site: stackoverflow
```

When I send a similar (semantically identical, apart from the lack of `filter` parameter) request from my Rails web app to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/40769255/flags/add`:

```
option_id: 22992
key: my API key
preview: true
access_token: my write token
site: stackoverflow
id: 40769255
```

I get the following 400 Bad Request:

```
{"error_id":400,"error_message":"comment","error_name":"bad_parameter"}
```

I've also tried including a `comment` parameter. With an empty parameter, this fails with the same error. With a 16-character `comment` parameter, the request *succeeds* (for a NAA flag, which *doesn't* require a comment). Which leads me on to bug #2...

**The flag doesn't get created.**

As I said, I was trying to flag #40769255 on Stack Overflow. After the successful request, I opened the flag menu on the answer, expecting it to tell me that I have an NAA flag cast. It doesn't.

Neither does my flag history list any flags on that answer.

This is *definitely* a bug, since the API request should not return a 200 OK unless the flag has actually been created.

Comment: Preview:true means you are not creating a flag, so the second part is not a bug. About the first one, I don't have an idea, perhaps the option_id isn't stable and you should fetch it from the rails app?

Comment: @zaq that explains it. As for the first one, the option_id comes from a previous API request.

Comment: `option_id: 22992` is "other" which does require a comment

Comment: @Cai option IDs change per post

Comment: @Art you are right, I thought it was *available* IDs that changed per post not actual IDs

Comment: Too late for me to repro now, since the post is deleted. I wanted to double-check that the option_id was for indeed for NAA.  I've been using API to cast NAA flags for a long time, and it works fine for me. The NAA option is indexed [2] in the list returned by /flags/options